# Mysql: How does a rollback operation be performed inside InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, transaction-log, rollback

I would like to hear in simple words Please answer me in simple words to the question on the below scenario.

```
==============
Engine: Innodb
Trx1  : started and a DML is executed at 10:00 AM and rolled back 11:00 AM
==============
```

**Ques1:** When this DML be written to iblog files ?

**Ques2:** When the DML be written to binary log files ?

**Ques3:** Will the related data pages on disc be modified during 10:00 AM to 11:00 AM

**Ques4:** What happens to the above three(ib logs, binary logs and data pages) when
I issue ROLL BACK operation at 11:00 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this DML be written to iblog files ? -- "as needed" during the hour

When the DML be written to binary log files ? -- Never.  Information for the binlog is gathered, but not written until `COMMIT`.

Will the related data pages on disc be modified during 10:00 AM to 11:00 AM -- There *may* be modifications to the pages.  They will be invisible to the user.  Example:  "old" and "new" versions of records.  The "new" versions are not visible to other transactions (except maybe for certain tx_isolation modes).  The "new" versions will *eventually* be purged from the data pages after the `ROLLBACK`.

What happens to the above three(ib logs, binary logs and data pages) when
I issue ROLL BACK operation at 11:00 AM --

- iblogs -- a lot of activity to perform the `ROLLBACK`
- binlog -- nothing (the tmp RAM or file holding the pending transaction will be thrown away)
- data pages -- nothing visible (see above)

Comment: James, thank you for your inputs. Shall you please elaborate on the iblogs part in both cases.... (1. after issuing the DML and 2. after issuing ROLL BACK). Thank you once again.